# Scrapy's FormRequest not giving results

Tags: python, request, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to try and perform a search on [this](https://ww2.stj.jus.br/processo/pesquisa/?aplicacao=processos.ea) website.
The field I'm changing is *Número do Processo na ORIGEM*, with id 'idNumeroOriginario'.

However, the Post method doesn't seem to change anything on the page.

Here's the code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class MinimalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stj-spider'
    start_urls = ['https://ww2.stj.jus.br/processo/pesquisa/?aplicacao=processos.ea']

    def parse(self, response):
        headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'browserName': 'mozilla',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Referer': 'https://ww2.stj.jus.br/processo/pesquisa/?aplicacao=processos.ea',
        }
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            headers=headers,
            formid='idForm',
            formdata={'idNumeroOriginario': '1234'},
            callback=self.after_search,
        )

    def after_search(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)        
        print response.body
```

I have also tried with requests, but to no avail. There seems to be a hundred hidden inputs that made it really hard.

Anyways, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to change one line to make it work:

```
formdata={'idNumeroOriginario': '1234'},
```

See how here you are specifying `idNumeroOriginario` form value.

The problem is, `idNumeroOriginario` is an `id` value, but the form input `name` values are used as form request parameter names, change it to:

```
formdata={'numeroOriginario': '1234'},
```